# A-frame doesn't display my texture

Tags: aframe

Here is my code:
https://glitch.com/edit/#!/entertaining-garden?path=index.html:17:8

And where you can find the result: https://entertaining-garden.glitch.me/

I don't understand why my texture on line 20 isn't display at all... It's probably just a stupid thing I forget but I really can't figure it out!

Thank you if you can check it!

Comment: You should include at least a minimal, reproductive code example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not working, because You are assigning the `material` component to the entity twice:
1) in the template
2) inline (with the texture)

It's quite interesting, never tried giving two materials to an entity at once :)

reproduction [here](https://jsfiddle.net/pa9m3upx/)

---

Either remove the material from the template, or create a new component, which will assign the texture to the material like:

```
AFRAME.registerComponent("foo", {
  init: function() {
     this.el.setAttribute("material", "src", "myPic.jpg")
  }
})
```

Comment: Thanks, I succeeded! But by taking out the template component.. If I let it, blocks take random colors and I don't really understand why. But that's ok, I will find out, thanks again!